# matlab: linear regression and different error weight

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, least-squares, model-fitting

I have a model

```
y = a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + ... + a20 * x20
```

y is in range [-100000, 100000].
It is important for me to get regression where I get minimum in relative errors. Absolute errors are less important.

What matlab function should I use?
And how huge should be my sample?

And what is the easiest way to calculate `R_adj` ?
Is `R_adj` a good variable for evaluating model you propose or it that model one should use something else?

Comment: First you need to find out which regression method best suits your problem, that's a theoretical math problem. Once you did that I'm quite sure we can find a function. My first thought would be to use "Weighted least squares", but I'm not sure, please check on that. There is then a [matlab function](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/curvefit/least-squares-fitting.html#bq_5kr9-3).

Comment: what is `R_adj`? how do you define it? can you write a mathematical formula for the error given a model `a0...a20`?

Comment: `R_adj` is the "Coefficient of determination". It's useful for model evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered normalizing your `x` points by the corresponding `y` values?
Instead of fitting `x_i1`, `x_i2`, ..., `x_i20` to `y_i` for all samples `i` you have, you may want to consider fitting `x_i1/y_i`, `x_i2/y_2`,... `x_i20/y_i` to `1`.

If you decide to do so, you need to construct a matrix `X` of size `n`-by-`20` (the `i`-th row is the `i`-th sampe). Then:

```
>> n = size(x,1); % number of samples
>> nX = bsxfun( @rdivide, X, y); % divide each sample i with corresponding y_i
>> a = nX \ ones(n,1); % solution using normalization
```

You can compare this solution to un-normalize least-squares

```
>> non_a = X \ y;
```

Comment: @user2861714 your question is phrased in a very vague manner - it is not clear what exactly you are trying to do. Please define your objective function (mathematically) in a rigorous way and then we can see how to solve it programatically/algorithmically.

Comment: I just building my model, it's crude now and I want to find out a proper model for my goal.. I think the dividing model is good enough.